# How to include showcased work at a conference in a resume?

Tags: citations, conference

I am working on adding to my fledgling academic resume and I'm not sure about how to cite one of the work.

My team designed an educational game that was showcased at a conference. There was no presentation *per se*. People could come take a look and try it but that is all. Is this even worth including in an academic resume? If so, how would I go about including this in APA? I don't want to make it look like I did a presentation when I did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your showcased work was not published in the conference proceedings either online or offline.

If you did not receive any written acknowledgement about this showcased work in the form of a certificate, then it is not wise to write this in CV. There are many activities we do while studying, but not all go to CV.

If you have any proof for the same (in the form of a certificate), you could add the following information into your CV:

(Author, Year, Title, Conf, Venue) e.g.

Lastname1, Firstname1, Lastname2, Firstname2, (2018) *"A demonstration on the XYZ Game,"* in International Conference on Funny Games (ICFG), January 22-23, University of ABCD, Country. [Showcased work, unpublished]

Comment: No written form certificate but the professor who brought the work at the conference said it was something that could be put on a CV. Would this change your answer in any way? Should I ask my professor for some kind of written evidence?

Comment: @Emilie No. If your professor is aware of this and has advised to put on CV, that's okay. If she is a co-author or co-developer of this work, you may wish to write her name in your CV as well, as given in the above format (Author1, Author2, Year, Title, Conference, Venue)